# ASP Classic: Check if string only consists of valid chars

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic

I've been checking all over the internet but really can't find any specific solution of my problem.

How do I check if a string consists of only the declared valid characters?

I want my string to consists of only 0-9, A-Z and a-z

So the string `oifrmf9RWGEWRG3oi4m3ofm3mklwef-qæw` should be invalid because of `-` and `æ`
while the string `joidsamfoiWRGWRGmoi34m3f` should be valid.

I have been using the build-in RegExp to strip the strings, but is it possible to just make it check and return a boolean false or true?

my regexp:

```
set pw = new regexp
pw.global = true
pw.pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"

newstring = pw.replace("iownfiwefnoi3w4mtl3.-34ø'3", "")
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with the `.Test()` method?

Comment: Didn't know it existed :) Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do a [Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32x2hy1%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns True or False

```
If( pw.Test("string") ) Then
'' Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Try -

```
Dim myRegExp, FoundMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test("iownfiwefnoi3w4mtl3.-34ø'3")
```

If `FoundMatch` is true the RegEx engine has found a character that is not a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and your string is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
Set match = pw.execute("iownfiwefnoi3w4mtl3.-34ø'3")

if match.count > 0 then
   ' your pattern matched, so it's invalid
   badString = true
else
   badString = false
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replace you can look and see if there is a match on any characters outside the whitelist. The general for each match syntax is [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/24/Regular-Expressions-and-VBScript)

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z0-9] works...I tried it against your string here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2u7c3 and here http://regexpal.com/ ...take the carrot out. I also can't remember the regex engine vbscript uses but that might have something to do with your problem. This also works...

\D?\w

Comment: I know that the current string-thing works :)
My problem is, that now it just strips the string .. But i want it to check if the string contains invalid characters and not strip it :)